# Alignment to center in excel VBA: Code is not working

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub belajar_case()
Dim nilai As Single
Dim huruf As String
nilai = Cells(1, 1).Value

Range("A1:B1").Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = x1Center
End With

Select Case nilai
Case 0 To 20
huruf = "F"
Cells(1, 2) = huruf

Case 20 To 100
huruf = "E-A"
Cells(1, 2) = huruf

End Select
End Sub
```

This is my code. I want to align the cell to center, but it doesn't work. Message pop up and says "Run-time error '1004':Unable to set the HorizontalAlignment property of the Range class." When I debugged, it referred to line:
    .HorizontalAlignment = x1Center

Why is that so?

Comment: Firstly, take a look at this https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/how-to-avoid-the-select-method/ to see why using `Select` is a bad idea.

Comment: Hint: you wouldn't be asking this question if `Option Explicit` was specified at the top of every module.

Comment: What do you mean by Option explitcit?

Comment: @Yoshua At the top of each VBA code you type `Option Explicit`. When you are using Option Explicit VBA forces you to declare all your variables, so if you have a typo like in this case, it will show it for you instead of an error 1004

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have copied the code from somewhere. Or you made a typo.

It's not

`x1Center`: The second character is a numeric one (1)

It should be

`xlCenter`: The second character should be a `l` (alphabet)

Comment: Well, problem solved. Thanks bro. I thought it was 1 (one).

Comment: @Yoshua Please mark this post as the answer as described in the [Tour]. That is how you can say Thanks around here.